# Azure deployment from Azure DevOps failing to find zip package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-mobile-services

I am setting up a build and release pipeline for our Azure mobile app using **Azure DevOps**. I have completed the build and all works fine. I have a build task defined that creates the required zip file for deploying to Azure and this succeeds and the zip file is created at the root of the folder. But the deployment fails stating that the zip file cannot be found.

Here is my build task that creates the zip file.

[image]

And here is the output from the build step showing that it has successfully created the zip file.

[image]

But the deployment fails as it can't find the zip file.

[image]

Comment: did you publish the zip as artifact at the end of the build ?

Comment: Yes it's the very last step in my build pipeline

Comment: Your release does not seem to download any artifacts. there should be a "Download artifact..." task between "Initialize job" and "Deploy". Check the Agentphase of the release -> "Artifact download"

Comment: Sorry what is the "agent phase of the release" and how do I check it?

Comment: Open your release-definition -> go to the envirionment that is failing -> got to the agent-phase -> on the botton right there should be a section "artifact download"

Comment: Azure DevOps doesn't have environments. There are Artifacts and Stages.

Comment: i meant stages (formerly known as environments)

Comment: I have a TFS deployment to Azure which I setup without a problem, but am finding Azure DevOps a little confusing. In my build I have a task that creates the zip file, but my deployment doesn't find it. How should I create / publish the zip file so that my deployment can find it?

Comment: Creating the zip is only half of the rent. You still need to publish it so that it is assocciated with the build and releases can use the zip. There is a task called "Publish build artifacts". Configure it to publish your zip. Then in your release you can use the zip

Comment: Got it working. I wasn't publishing the zip file using the Publish Build Artifact task. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to publish the `.zip` file from your build using the **Publish Build Artifacts** task. That will make it available as an artifact to be linked into a release definition to be deployed.

[image]

Comment: I've substituted the variable $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) for $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) as suggested which creates the zip file D:\a\3\a\package.zip. The generated error is "Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\package.zip". The deployment is still not finding the zip file despite it being created successfully in the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) folder. It's looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: Wait, are these two things happening in a build and a release definition, separately? If that's the case, you need to publish an artifact from your build, then link the artifact into your release definition. The original paths were probably okay.

Comment: My build definition creates the zip file artifact as the final step in the pipeline. My release definition then attempts to deploy this zip file (but fails to locate it).

Comment: Are you using the Publish Artifact task?

Comment: I'm using an MSBUILD task to create the zip file. I can't see a Publish Artifact task.  I'm using Azure DevOps.

Comment: Got it. It's Publish Build Artifact. Let me check that out, cheers.

Comment: Got it working. I wasn't publishing the zip file using the Publish Build Artifact task. Thanks for all your help :)